# How to get my sudoku solver to read from text file in python?

Tags: python, text, sudoku

I am having trouble figuring out how to read from a text file for my Sudoku solver. So I can get it to read the board from a text file, and I can get my code to solve the board when it's in the code, but I can't bet them to read and solve together. This is what I have and I've tried a few methods to get it to possibly work, but I'm not understanding it. If anyone could help, I'd really appreciate it! Thanks!

```
board = []
with open('project.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
         board.append(line.strip('\n').split(','))
         if line != '':
             (board)

#backtracking
def solve(pr):
    find = find_empty(pr)
    if not find:
        return True
    else:
        row, col = find

    for r in range(1,10):
        if valid(pr, r, (row, col)):
            pr[row][col] = r

            if solve(pr):
                return True

            pr[row][col] = 0

    return False


def valid(pr, num, pos):
    # Check row
    for r in range(len(pr[0])):
        if pr[pos[0]][r] == num and pos[1] != r:
            return False

    # Check column
    for r in range(len(pr)):
        if pr[r][pos[1]] == num and pos[0] != r:
            return False

    # Check box
    box_x = pos[1] // 3
    box_y = pos[0] // 3

    for r in range(box_y*3, box_y*3 + 3):
        for c in range(box_x * 3, box_x*3 + 3):
            if pr[r][c] == num and (r,c) != pos:
                return False

    return True

#formatting
def print_board(pr):
    for r in range(len(pr)):
        if r % 3 == 0 and r != 0:
            print("- - - - - - - - - - - - - ")

        for c in range(len(pr[0])):
            if c % 3 == 0 and c != 0:
                print(" | ", end="")

            if c == 8:
                print(pr[r][c])
            else:
                print(str(pr[r][c]) + " ", end="")


def find_empty(pr):
    for r in range(len(pr)):
        for c in range(len(pr[0])):
            if pr[r][c] == 0:
                return (r, c)  # row, col

    return None

solve(board)
print_board(board)
```

my txt file looks like this:

```
003020600
900305001
001806400
008102900
700000008
006708200
002609500
800203009
005010300
```

Comment: What does your `project.txt` look like?  You aren't converting to integers.

Comment: If that's your format, why are you doing `split(',')`?  You can just convert to list: `board.append(list(line.strip()))`.

Comment: Your sample only has 8 lines.

Comment: Well, it's wrong.  If there are no commas in the data, then you can't expect to find any.  I've made my suggested change in your code and it's getting through without error.

Comment: I did the changes and the board shows up properly, so that works, but it's not solving it

Comment: You need to convert the characters to integers.  I posted an answer that works.

Comment: Optimization:  You don't have to check `and pos[1] !=r` and `and pos[0] != r` and `and (r,c) != pos` in your checker.  You call the function BEFORE you have placed the new value, so it's never going to be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this one-line change, your code solves the sudoku, even after I fill in 0s for the missing row.

```
board = []
with open('project.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
         board.append(list(map(int,line.strip())))
```

I added a `print_board` before solving.  That's why you see it twice.

Output:

```
9 0 0  | 3 0 5  | 0 0 1
0 0 1  | 8 0 6  | 4 0 0
0 0 8  | 1 0 2  | 9 0 0
- - - - - - - - - - - - - 
7 0 0  | 0 0 0  | 0 0 8
0 0 6  | 7 0 8  | 2 0 0
0 0 2  | 6 0 9  | 5 0 0
- - - - - - - - - - - - - 
8 0 0  | 2 0 3  | 0 0 9
0 0 5  | 0 1 0  | 3 0 0
0 0 0  | 0 0 0  | 0 0 0

9 2 4  | 3 7 5  | 8 6 1
5 3 1  | 8 9 6  | 4 7 2
6 7 8  | 1 4 2  | 9 3 5
- - - - - - - - - - - - - 
7 5 3  | 4 2 1  | 6 9 8
1 9 6  | 7 5 8  | 2 4 3
4 8 2  | 6 3 9  | 5 1 7
- - - - - - - - - - - - - 
8 4 7  | 2 6 3  | 1 5 9
2 6 5  | 9 1 7  | 3 8 4
3 1 9  | 5 8 4  | 7 2 6
```

Comment: Ok, I understand now! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this.

```
def loadBoard(fname):
    board = []
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            board.append([int(x) for x in line.strip('\n')])
    return board
```

This is based on the what you said the input is in your comment to Mike_S's answer, in other words just rows of numbers with no separators (unless you include the newlines of course).  It seems to me like you're using the input as ints, so you would want to convert them to ints as I do in this example.  Then to get the board, you just do:

```
board = loadBoard('project.txt')
```

I hope this helps.  If I misunderstood something and you let me know, I will do my best to come back and correct it.

Edited because I forgot to put

```
board = []
```

inside the function.